# How do i remove animated icon

Tags: customization

Hey so i have adriana theme and there are these three animated icons that are on the page and i want to remove them.

and after removing the icons i want the three paragraphs in brown to stay in that order but just move up where the icons used to be.

PLease help how would i do this i have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your theme might have an option for making the icons hidden. In case it hasn't a specific option for that, you could achieve what you want with CSS in order to control your website's styles.

Most modern themes have a custom css option under their settings so you can set place your custom css styles. Search for that kind of option, place the following there and Save changes.

```
.home-title.i-container {
    display: none !important;
}
```

The above would hide the animated icon element through the whole website. In case you want to hide the icons only on your home page, use the following instead:

```
.home .home-title.i-container {
    display: none !important;
}
```

If you can't find an option for placing custom css code through your theme's settings, you have to manually edit your theme's main style.css file and re-upload it to your server.

Comment: Thanks a ton you saved my life! I have another question. I want to add an image on the right hand side of the about section. Wordpress has no option to do that and i don't have access to the html so how would i do that?

Comment: By editing your page template under WordPress admin you're able to add images to your posts and pages. I'd suggest you to explore your theme's functionalities while editing a page. It's hard to say how you'd achieve what you expect without testing the theme. Maybe your theme uses a custom page builder plugin that gives you custom options for adding different image sizes and styles, maybe not, but in either case, you still have WordPress option for embedding images on your posts/pages. E.g: https://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages

Comment: After inspecting your code, even not knowing where the about section's content comes from, you could try to add your image to the content's source such as `<img class="about-img" src="http://jodeshappytail.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/peanut-butter21.png">` and then style it with css accordingly e.g: .about-img { position: relative; float: right; } - See a screen shot: https://cldup.com/IrxGq8X1iD.png

Comment: Hey i am trying to make a few changes to my portfolio section but i can't figure out how

this is my website: http://sherrysanimalkookies.com/

the portfolio kookie section. Firstly i want the heading of dog kookies to be first but wordpress arranges the skills alphabetically. How would i get around that and arrange it how i want it? Secondly i Want the images to be circular not boxes all stuck together and third i want to fix the image size as the bottom pictures have someones head being cut off.. Please help i have been trying all day but nothing works.